# While loop doesn't execute a line anymore

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm currently working in a simple trading bot which duty is to detect if a position is open and if a condition is True, then close that position. The problem I met is that the code inside the `while` loop is executed for the entire only once and only the first time the script is run, then it will execute only the first `if` and it will not go further to the next `if` even if the conditions are `True`.

When its looping through for the second time, the `if current_price > entry_price:` is not going to be read and same on `if current_price < entry_price_short:` even if that condition is true. I'm struggling to find a way. Help Pls

here's the code:

```
while True:
    POSITIONS = get_positions_open() # this function return a list of 4 items,
                                     # only the first element can change, depend,
                                     # ['long', size, leverage, entryprice] 
    open_sl = POSITIONS[0]                      
    entry_price = POSITIONS[3]

    # 'Bullish' and 'Bearish' are 2 engulfing candles built outside the loop.
    # 'ONE_HIGH' and 'ONE_LOW' is a function that requests data for 1 minute candle 
    # timeframe.

    # First Condition: if a position is currently open
    if open_sl == 'long':      
        print('Long is currently open')
        # Second condition
        if current_price > entry_price:
            print('Current price is over the entry price')
            # Third condition
            if Bearish == True:
                close_position(symbol, 'short', QTY)
                print('Close pos - Bear candle Met')
            elif current_price < ONE_HIGH:
                close_position(symbol, 'long', QTY)
                print('3rd close pos')
            
    # First Condition: if a position is currently open
    elif open_sl == 'short':
        print('Short is currently open')
        # Second condition
        if current_price < entry_price_short:
            print('Current price is under the entry price')
            # Third condition
            if Bullish == True:
                close_position(symbol, 'short', QTY)
                print('Close pos - Bull candle Met')
            elif current_price > ONE_LOW:
                close_position(symbol, 'short', QTY)
                print('3rd close pos') 
    
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Are you sure `get_positions_open` returns something different each time?

Comment: One thing to note, the if and while statements themselves are doing exactly what they're supposed to, but the condition itself is false. Try `print(open_sl)` before the first if statement